# Filter Outlook calendar based on status of individual occurrence in meeting series

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

In Microsoft Outlook (Microsoft 365 app), I want to use Filters on my Calendar page to exclude recurring meetings when I haven't accepted the series, but still show individual occurrences of the meeting that I have accepted.

**What I have so far:** If I open the Filter dialog [View > Current View > View Settings... > Filters...], on the Advanced tab I can add "Meeting Status equals Accepted".  On the SQL tab, this is translated into `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82180003" = 3`.  The effect of this on recurring meetings is to hide the ones where I haven't accepted the Series.  But this includes hiding the individual occurrences I have accepted.

I'm hoping to add `OR <other condition>`, where the latter condition would select individual occurrences that have been accepted.  If there's some MAPI property like the one above, except for the status of a single meeting occurrence rather than the series, then I think that would meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

For more information on canonical properties, see [MAPI Canonical Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-canonical-properties).

Besides, this is a reference guide to the available search operators and search fields and how to use them:

https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/searchcommands.htm